# Flexslider broken links

Tags: navigation, javascript

I have a very weird problem with flexslider.

Everything was working ok, but suddenly flexslider stopped to show the images im adding.

My observations are:

- Flexslider rewrites urls to the path, where there is NO images
- there is a access denied warning in drupal logs but my permissions are set to 775/755

Whole flexslider mechanism is working correct, its cycling and stuff, but there is no content inside.

I will appreciate any help, and thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like an issue with your files directory permissions. Specifically, the permissions on the directory that contains the image style derivatives for the flexslider. My guess is that they are not being created properly.

Comment: The problem was my folder containing those files... Drupal couldn't get access to it. But I went to the File System tab and changed to the new one. Now it works like charm :) Thanks